# Pairing Unique Columns MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique, mysql-workbench

I'd like to know how to make paired columns unique key?

I'm working on MySQL workbench, and right now I've set two columns (follow,following) to be UQ, I'm assuming this is Unique Key?

So when I tried to insert rows, I tried to insert

```
follow      following
  3              5
  3              6
```

But follow is unique key. But i'd like to only do unique key for a pair only, not individual numbers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken you have only set a unique key for each column. Maybe you want compound column to be `UNIQUE`, try

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD CONSTRAINT tb_UQ UNIQUE (follow, following)
```

if you run the `ALTER` statement, the example data above is valid but if you try to insert another pair of `3, 5`, it is guaranteed to fail.

Comment: Thanks this works. I had to delete some stuff, but essentially I got the point, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you created the table with `follow` as the PRIMARY key, then the RDBMS will enforce uniqueness based on that column alone.

As an alternate to JW's suggestion, you can change the PRIMARY KEY:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD CONSTRAINT tb_UQ PRIMARY KEY (follow, following);
```